# angular 2 dynamic form with dependent fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I need to create form with different blocks which depends on each other, some inputs should make other inputs appear/disappear, be required or change some other validations.

As far as I understand, template forms won't give me those features or it would be just kind of messy to scale. So I looked into "reactive" forms since they would allow me to get config from back-end and render the form based on this config.

But the problem is that, **I have to implement material design in this project, specifically material.angular.io** and right now, I have no idea how to get this all together in a working prototype.

Comment: Take small steps. Create a prototype using regular form elements first. Once you get that working, worry about replacing the default form elements with Material ones (which is easy enough).

Answer (score 0):

Try using EventEmitters available with Angular2